# Ajax-updating c:choose from inside c:when does not seem to have any effect

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, jstl, conditional-rendering

I would like to update the attribute "isAdult" by clicking on button A, and hide this button A then display the button B and C.

Facelet extract :

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${userBean.isAdult}">
       (display button A)
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
       (display button B)
       (display button C)
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Function "updateIsAdult" (code was minimised) :

```
    @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped
    public class UserBean implements Serializable { 
       ...
         public boolean updateIsAdult(){
              isAdult =  true;
          }
       ...
    }
```

I try to do this with an AJAX Call :

```
  <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{userBean.updateIsAdult}"/>
```

But it doesn't work : the method updateIsAdult is called but the value "isAdult" isn't updated, and the test isn't updated.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Configuration :

- Mojarra 2.2.0
- JSF API 2.2.0
- JSTL 1.2

The way to do may not be the appropriate one ?

Comment: My true question is : Can we refresh values used in a JSPF Page ? :/

Comment: Of course, we can answer "yes", and it would be a good start and a message of hope...But I want to know whether the way to do I've used, is correct or not.
I've a doubt about the "text blue"....I have just added some information, but I'm not sure that it will help you :/

Comment: Magically or not, doesn't matter :)
Yes that's why I have tried to use explicit terms for method or attribute.

The idea is that the JSF will be refreshed (the attribute "isAdult" for example, and consequently, the test) after clicking on one button.

Comment: I have superficial knowledge of JSF. I have worked on an existing project since 2 weeks and used JSF on the basis of existing code.
I have been advised to use ajax to make what I've just described above.

(Extra info : The library PrimeFaces is included in the project.)

Comment: Yes, my mistake ! I've just edited my post. Ok for the advice :) 

But I work with a tight deadline, so it's hard to take a pause on the project.